# why is django returning form.is_valid == false?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

Everytime I use this form I get form.is_valid() == False . When I do print(form.errors) I get :

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>reservation_code<ul class="errorlist"><li>Client with this Reservation code already exists.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

But the whole point of the form is to get the details of the reservation, by entering an already existing reservation code. So how can I change this so the form returns valid?

Here is the view:

```
def reservationView(request):

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request,'aplikacija/reservations.html')
    else:
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            code = form.cleaned_data['reservation_code']
      
            try:
                client = Client.objects.filter(reservation_code=code)
                tour = client.tour.destination
                client.delete()
                return render(request,'aplikacija/reservations.html',{'infoMsg':f'You have successfully cancelled your trip to {tour}'})
            except:
                form = ReservationForm()
                return render(request,'aplikacija/cancelReservation.html',{'form':form,'infoMsg':'INVALID RESERVATION CODE'})
            
        else:
            form = ReservationForm()
            print(form.errors)
            return render(request,'aplikacija/cancelReservation.html',{'form':form,'infoMsg':'FORM INVALID'})
```

This is the model :

```
class Client(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    number_of_guests =models.IntegerField()
    tour = models.ForeignKey(Tour,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=15,default=0)
    reservation_code = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
```

This is the form class :

```
class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Client
        fields = ('reservation_code',)
        widgets = {
            'reservation_code':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'clientFormField'})
        }
```

And here is the template :

```
{% extends 'aplikacija/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h2 id="mostPopularTitle">Please enter your reservation code</h2>

    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'reservation_details' %}" class="contactFormTab clientForm">
        {{infoMsg}}
        
    
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Get reservation details</button>
    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

Does anyone have an idea why the form is always returning invalid?

Comment: Hi there, did you check in your db if exists already one client with "reservation_code" that you are saving? Don't forget that you defined unique=True, this creates the constraint unique field.

Comment: I'm not saving , I'm just checking if the reservation code exists and then getting the client details based on the existing reservation code.. so that shouldn't be a confict, although I put it to be unique

Answer (score 0):

For this problem as you said

> the whole point of the form is to get the details of the reservation,
> by entering an already existing reservation code

You are doing it on a wrong way. If you want to get the details based on the reservation_code you need to change some logic.

There is no point on creating a `ModelForm` but you can use simply `Form` if you want.

You can change your form method from `POST` to `GET`.

```
 <form  action="{% url 'reservation_details' %}" class="contactFormTab clientForm">
        {{infoMsg}}
        <input type='text' name='reservation_code' placeholder='Reservation Code'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Get reservation details</button>
    </form>
```

Now in the view.

```
def reservation_view(request):
   reservation_code = request.GET.get('reservation_code')
   client = Clinet.objects.get(reservation_code=reservation_code)
   return render(request, 'your_template', {'client':client}
```

Now in the template you can get the client details with this reservation_code

```
{{clinet.name}} {{client.surname}}
```

Comment: I used regular forms like you said.. definately better option. Only this time I always get 'INVALID RESERVATION CODE' . I copy the code directly from the database, and stil it acts as if the client with that code doesnt exist..

Comment: You are using  [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/). Why to use modelform if you are not saving the objects on the database